# What is the best way to fill Combo box?

Tags: c#

I have 3 form's in my project

When I open form 3, I fill Combo box with data (from DataBase)

it take's time......

How I can fill this Combo box only one time when the program is open ?

(in the first form - form1)

thank's in advance

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I would assume it was done because the question is too vague to really give a good answer to.

Answer (score 4):

There are a million ways to do this, and your question is pretty vague.  is it the same data in all three combo boxes?  Regardless, you want to load the data and store the lists in memory when you application first initializes.  There are a lot of good, and a lot of bad ways to do this.  Then when each form comes up, check to see if the list in memory is filled, if it is, bind to that list. (If not, of course, fill the list from the database, and then bind to it).

The overall concept is to preload the data, and then always check your memory persistence before going to the database.

### Edit

To quickly list a good and bad way of storing these values in memory before I turn in for the night.  I'll try to expand on this in the morning.

The best way would be to create a memory repository layer in your application, and have your business objects poll it before heading to the database, but there is some complexity in using this sort of model (mainly dealing with concurrency issues.)

The worst way would be to just declare some global collections of data somewhere, and pull them directly into your UI.

Comment: Can you please list the good ways and bad ways of storing data in memory??

Comment: I apologize for the quick and vague edit to answer your question, I'll try to expand upon it a bit in the morning.